# saving document in space with blank character in alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I work with alfresco 4.0

I have a problem to save document in special space in alfresco named in arabic language.

for this example I didn't have problem :

```
/app:company_home/cm:تجربة
```

but I have problem when the space witch is created in alfresco is named in arabic language and have blank character . like this :

```
/app:company_home/cm:تجربة ثانية
```

in this case I can't save document in alfresco

**updated :**

also I have the same problem when I have a folder named in english and have escape character like this :

**His Excellency the Secretary**

**Reporter Secretariat**

this is the document to save document in alfresco

```
 public String saveDocument(File file, String name, String folderName, String userName, String pwd, String code)
        throws Exception {
        File file_BC = file;
        try {
            BarCodeEngine barCodeEngine = new BarCodeEngine(file, code);
            file_BC = barCodeEngine.setBarCode();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] contentByte = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file_BC));

        // Start the session
        AuthenticationUtils.startSession(userName, pwd);

        try {
            // Create a reference to the parent where we want to create content
            Store storeRef = new Store(Constants.WORKSPACE_STORE, "SpacesStore");
            ParentReference companyHomeParent = new ParentReference(storeRef, null, folderName, Constants.ASSOC_CONTAINS, null);

            // Assign name
            companyHomeParent.setChildName("cm:" + name);

            // Construct CML statement to create content node
            // Note: Assign "1" as a local id, so we can refer to it in subsequent
            //       CML statements within the same CML block
            NamedValue[] contentProps = new NamedValue[1];
            contentProps[0] = Utils.createNamedValue(Constants.PROP_NAME, name);

            CMLCreate create = new CMLCreate("1", companyHomeParent, null, null, null, Constants.TYPE_CONTENT, contentProps);

            // Construct CML statement to add titled aspect
            NamedValue[] titledProps = new NamedValue[2];
            titledProps[0] = Utils.createNamedValue(Constants.PROP_TITLE, name);
            titledProps[1] = Utils.createNamedValue(Constants.PROP_DESCRIPTION, name);

            CMLAddAspect addAspect = new CMLAddAspect(Constants.ASPECT_TITLED, titledProps, null, "1");

            // Construct CML Block
            CML cml = new CML();
            cml.setCreate(new CMLCreate[] { create });
            cml.setAddAspect(new CMLAddAspect[] { addAspect });

            // Issue CML statement via Repository Web Service and retrieve result
            // Note: Batching of multiple statements into a single web call
            UpdateResult[] result = WebServiceFactory.getRepositoryService().update(cml);
            Reference content = result[0].getDestination();

            // Write some content
            ContentServiceSoapBindingStub contentService = WebServiceFactory.getContentService();

            //String text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
            ContentFormat contentFormat = new ContentFormat("text/plain", "UTF-8");
            Content contentRef = contentService.write(content, Constants.PROP_CONTENT, contentByte, contentFormat);
            System.out.println("Document are created successfully. UID:= " + content.getUuid());

            return content.getUuid();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        } finally {
            // End the session
            AuthenticationUtils.endSession();

            //System.exit(0);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I try to replace **espace** with this character : **+** without success

```
saveAttachement(file,
                                     fileName +
                                    System.currentTimeMillis(), container.replace(" ","+"),
                                    USER_NAME, PASSWORD,
                                    code);
```

this is the old container with espace

**/app:company_home/cm:His Excellency the Secretary/cm:Reporter Secretariat**

and this is the container with +

**/app:company_home/cm:His+Excellency+the Secretary/cm:Reporter+Secretariat**

in alfresco's log  I didn't find any error

Comment: I can t reproduce this on my alfresco 5.0.d . What does the tomcat logfile say when your upload fails?

Comment: thank you for your answer,

but I found the same error in folder named in english and have escape character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try encoding your folderName with ISO9075.encode(folderName).

Lucene search syntax needs encoding of spaces using ISO9075. I thik this is what happens somewhere behind the scenes of your ParentReference usage.